# Access User Data Outside of AuthStateListener Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know how to access user data such as UID and display name inside an AuthStateListener for user authentication in Firebase. I want to be able to access these variables outside of the AuthStateListener. I tried assigning this data to variables within the AuthStateListener and then simply printed it to the console. This is a sample of my code. Assume all variables have been declared correctly and there are no compile-time errors with the code:

```
//Inside onCreate
mListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null){
                //mName  has been declared previously outside of the onCreate() method
                mName = user.getUid();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mListener);
        System.out.println("UID: " + mName);
    }
```

Yet, the console says UID: null. How can I make it show the actual UID of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to have solved my own problem. I got the UID and name via a splash screen and then passed that data through an intent.

In the splash screen:

```
mListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null){
                Intent toHome = new Intent(splash.this, home.class);
                toHome.putExtra("uid", user.getUid());
                toHome.putExtra("name", user.getDisplayName());
                startActivity(toHome);
            }
            else{
                Intent toLogin = new Intent(splash.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(toLogin);
            }
        }
    };
```

If the user exists, then it will go to the main page, but otherwise, the user needs to log in (at least in my case). Of course, I added this listener in the onStart() and removed it in the onStop() method. I added the UID and DisplayName to the intent using the format:

```
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
```

The home class receives these two pieces of data and this is how it deals with it. Assume all variables have been initialized correctly in the following snippet:

```
//This is inside the home class
mUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("uid");
mName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

And presto! I can access the UID and Name of the user currently signed in!

Comment: Good to hear that you figured out how to solve the problem. If you show the code of how you did this, it will be more useful to others who may encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also print the uid inside the callback, after you assign mName.

Comment: Well, this is not what I want as my result. The printing part is just a test to see if mName has been assigned the correct value, not null.